# Java program keep infinite loop without any error message

Tags: java, multithreading

Here i'm learning `volatile` keyword and java memory model, code below:

```
public class VolatileTest {
    public volatile int inc = 0;

    public void increase() {
        inc++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final VolatileTest test = new VolatileTest();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            new Thread(){
                public void run() {
                    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                        test.increase();
                };
            }.start();
        }

        while(Thread.activeCount()>1)  
            Thread.yield();
        System.out.println(test.inc);
    }
}
```

what't wrong with it? maybe something caused by the mac os? hope some one help me out?

Comment: "what't wrong with it?" - What error do you get?

Comment: program without any error and any output and still keep running for about one more minutes.

Comment: You may want to use Thread.join to wait for the workers to finish. Thread.activeCount is very probably not doing what you expect.

Comment: Wouldn't `Thread.activeCount()` always return `>1`... Your threads are not being closed anywhere from what I can see.

Comment: @px06 What? After the loop they just die. What do you mean with "threads are not being closed" ? How do you "close" a thread?

Comment: As a sidenote: Please go through [ask] to improve future questions. You'll get better answers quicker. (And Upvotes)

Comment: you may not understand such code snippet mean, i just to mess the order of multiple threads.just test the volatile, because some time one thread just read the volatile value and  become blocked and another thread switch to read its value and change it, but such value will not spread to the the previous read thread cache and it will change it value from what have read previous but not current real one. so that two threads all done increase operation but result still 1.

Comment: How do you know if you are stuck in an infinite loop? Which is probably before the output. "you may not understand such code snippet mean" - be assured - we *do* understand ;)

Comment: if you run such program multiple times and can not get the result 100 for just one time.conclusion should has been proved.or you can set the loop value for 1000, the appearing possibility will be more.

Comment: Your results are invalid because the stop-condition is unreliable. So your conclusions are based on false data. Apply @NicolasFilottos's answer and repeat your tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your test `Thread.activeCount() > 1` will never be `false` as you have at least 2 threads that will still be running/active in the same group of threads after your threads die, which are:

1. The `main` thread (the current one)
2. The `Monitor Ctrl-Break` thread

You can check it by calling [`Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().list()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#list--) to print the list of all the threads that are in the group of the current thread so at worse it should rather be  `Thread.activeCount() > 2`.

---

But anyway it is not a good practice to rely on `Thread.activeCount()` for such thing as **it is not reliable** since it is only an estimate value, you should rather use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to synchronize your threads as next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    // CountDownLatch to be decremented 10 times to release awaiting threads
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ...
                } finally {
                    // Decrement it as the task is over
                    latch.countDown();
                }

            };
        }.start();
    }
    // Await until the countdown reaches 0
    latch.await();
    System.out.println(test.inc);
}
```